# Wild Draw Color Card in UNO Flip: How do we know that other person has drawn until matching color

Tags: uno-flip

As per UNO Flip Rules, Wild Draw Color Card – When you play this card, the next player must draw until they get a color of your choosing (no matter how many cards they have to draw to do so) and lose their turn.

But how can we ensure or know that the other player has drawn until they got the color of our choosing? They can lie, right?

Comment: Are you concerned about them drawing fewer cards than they have to, more cards than they have to, or both?

Comment: Both in general. I felt like the rules are not well thought out.

Answer (score 1):

Under the base rules of the game you can't know and have to trust them as there is no way to see what cards they are drawing. The only way to know with 100% certainty would be to create a house rule requiring them to reveal every card that they draw. However that would put them at a disadvantage as other players would have a good idea about what was in their hand.

Comment: You could also have a "challenge" rule llke you do for playing a Wild +4.

Comment: Just have them show the final matching card. If they want to draw more cards than required, that's on them...

Comment: @ilkkachu That only means the final card they draw is matching but they could have also drawn other matching cards and chosen to continue to draw for various reasons.

Comment: @JoeW, yes, and if the aim of the game is to get rid of your cards, that doesn't seem like an obvious advantage.

Comment: @ilkkachu True but there are players that would lie to draw more cards for various reasons. Not drawing enough isn’t the only concern when playing a game like uno.

Comment: I felt like having a house rule of playing the matching card, can at least stop players from taking fewer cards.